# Adding a non-standard font to Sharepoint

Tags: css, branding, custom

I have a non-standard font file in .eot format and use the following CSS syntax to embed it into the master page:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Myfontfamily;
    src: url("http://server/_layouts/STYLES/Fonts/myfont.eot") format("embedded-opentype");
}

.customfont
{
    font-family: Myfontfamily;  
}
```

On my master page I have the following HTML:

```
<p class="customfont">Some random text</p>
```

It works fine, when used in a plain ASP.NET site (within the same IIS instance), but not in SharePoint. Custom font is not applied on the SharePoint master page.
Do I need to make any additional actions for SharePoint?
I also need this non-standard font to appear in the Content Editor web part, is it possible?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but could you change you're URL to point to relative path? 
In other words try to change your url to something like ("/_layout/STYLES/fonyts/myfont.eot")

Comment: you should also register your css files (csslink/cssregistration) within your  file.master

Comment: How can i use sansa fonts.
Will it work with sharepoint?Does microsoft support it?
Cheers